# Unknown functions in an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having a problem with an integral that I do not understand. The form of my equation is $2Kp(x)/dx = -p(x)g$. I need to integrate this, but I'm not sure how to integrate it. Assuming I move the dx to the right side of the equation and integrate will it be $(-p(x)gx) - ((-p(x)^2/2)g)$?

Comment: The form is strange.  $/dx$ means what?

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere.  There can never be just one "$d$" quantity in an equation.  Otherwise you are saying something like "3 equals tiny" or "5 equals infinity".

Comment: That is the form the professor gave me, honestly I don't understand it either. The original problem was $P = K*p^2$ and $dP/dr = -pg$. You substitute K*p^2 into dP/dr and take the derivative to get 2Kp/dx. It makes no sense to me and I'm trying to understand her methods.

Comment: SInce $2KP/dx$ is wrong, you need to ask your professor.